# What does "There are no namespaces currently available." on the fabric8 console mean?

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, fabric8

I just completed the instructions given [here](http://fabric8.io/guide/getStarted/gke.html) on how to install fabric8 on Google Compute Engine.

Here's what connecting to the console gets me:

[image]

What does it mean? Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a [namespace](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/namespaces.html)?

Comment: Hi Robert, Thanks!. Running `kubectl get namespaces` gives me 2 namespaces named `default` and `kube-system`.
Do you mean that I should add another one for fabric8 to bootstrap correctly?

Comment: Those two namespaces are created automatically. Try creating a new custom namespace to see if that helps.

Comment: Oh sorry I missed that. Just created a new namespace, but that doesn't change anything from the fabric8's pow.

Comment: Does the fabric8 console's logs show any errors? If it can't find any namespaces it seems likely that it can't connect to the apiserver (maybe an auth issue?).

Comment: What version of the fabric8 console are you using? 2.2.28 (as referenced in the instructions you linked to) doesn't exist any longer, and the latest version appears to be 2.2.98.

Comment: Following the instructions I get the same error you do and the javascript console shows the message: "WebSocket network error: OSStatus Error -9807: Invalid certificate chain". It seems like you should file a bug against the fabric8 folks.

Comment: Thanks Robert, that's good to know. However at the time I did not realise how different the various flavours of fabric8 behaved. This was trying to get things to work on top of Kubernetes. I'm now using the openshift-v3 variant and it's working a lot better. It all feels very alpha though. Wondering if there are any more mature alternatives.